# Select by pair of values

Tags: mysql

I have a table (with multiple rows) that, in order to simplify things, let's consider like this:

```
Table: data
+---+--------+-------+-----+---------+
|id | name   |objId  |src  | type    |
+---+--------+-------+-----+---------+
```

In this table, ther can be multiple entries for the same `name`, however, only one should have the `descriptor` type. The one with the `descriptor` type specifies the default source in the `src` column.

I would like a query where, considering I know the default src for each name, to get the entries from the `data` table that have that src.

One solution would be something like this:
`SELECT * FROM data WHERE (objId=<id1> AND type=<dflt1>) OR (objId=<id2> AND type=<dflt2>) OR ... OR (objId=<idN> AND type=<dfltN>) AND type<>descriptor`

However, i would like to know if there is a simpler (faster) way of doing this.

```
example:
+---+--------+-------+-----+----------+
|id | name   |objId  |src  | type     |
+---+--------+-------+-----+----------+
|1  | file1  | 1     | srv |descriptor|
+---+--------+-------+-----+----------+
|2  | file 1 | 1     | srv |data      |
+---+--------+-------+-----+----------+
|3  | file 1 | 1     | srv |data      |
+---+--------+-------+-----+----------+
|4  | file 1 | 1     | lcl |data      |
+---+--------+-------+-----+----------+
|5  | file 2 | 2     | lcl |descriptor|
+---+--------+-------+-----+----------+
|6  | file 2 | 2     | srv |data      |
+---+--------+-------+-----+----------+
|7  | file 2 | 2     | lcl |data      |
+---+--------+-------+-----+----------+

Query should return entries with IDs: 2, 3, 7
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use a subquery to restrict the records in `data` to only those whose `src` value matches the `src` value in the descriptor record for each object group:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM data t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT objId, src
    FROM data
    WHERE type = 'descriptor'
) t2
    ON t1.src = t2.src AND t1.objId = t2.objId AND t1.type != 'descriptor'
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT * FROM data 
    WHERE (objId,type) in (select objid,type from data where type<>'descriptor')
```

add all combinations of id and dflt in "in" clause

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.objId = t2.objId AND t1.id  <> t2.id AND t1.src = t2.src
WHERE t1.type = 'descriptor'
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1111c6/1)

Answer (score 0):

Consider to normalize your tables and never have problems like that again.

Table `objects`:

```
| objId |   name | defaultSrc |
|-------|--------|------------|
|     1 | file 1 |        srv |
|     2 | file 2 |        lcl |
```

Table `data`:

```
| id | objId | src |
|----|-------|-----|
|  2 |     1 | srv |
|  3 |     1 | srv |
|  4 |     1 | lcl |
|  6 |     2 | srv |
|  7 |     2 | lcl |
```

Then yor query would be:

```
select o.name, d.* 
from objects o 
join data d
    on  d.objId = o.objId 
    and d.src   = o.defaultSrc;
```

Result:

```
|   name | id | objId | src |
|--------|----|-------|-----|
| file 1 |  2 |     1 | srv |
| file 1 |  3 |     1 | srv |
| file 2 |  7 |     2 | lcl |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00a5d/1)

This way you will not just have simpler queries, but also save disk/memory space and (more important) have less IO. Additionally adding proper foreign keys you can ensure data integrity.